# Xamarin Android .AAR results in DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: android, xamarin, java-binding

When trying to reference a .AAR java library binding we received the following error:

```
Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "\\####\####\Developer\Mobile Apps\Android\####.Android\Project Files\####.Xamarin.Android\obj\Release\__library_projects__\IntercomForXamarinAndroidBase\library_project_imports\res\drawable-xxhdpi\intercomsdk_chat_bubble_right_aligned_notail.9.png" (XA0000) (####.Xamarin.Android) monodroid
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because the file path was too long.

Installed windows hotfix:
[A file copy operation fails when files or folders have long paths in Windows Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2891362)